# ld: cannot find -lGL

Tags: 18.04, compiling

My compiler cannot compile a code complaining that it cannot find libGL. That is strange because it is already linked. When I do verbose I get:

```
attempt to open //usr/local/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libGL.so failed
attempt to open //usr/local/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libGL.a failed
attempt to open //lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libGL.so failed
attempt to open //lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libGL.a failed
attempt to open //usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libGL.so failed
attempt to open //usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libGL.a failed
attempt to open //usr/local/lib/libGL.so failed
attempt to open //usr/local/lib/libGL.a failed
attempt to open //lib/libGL.so failed
attempt to open //lib/libGL.a failed
attempt to open //usr/lib/libGL.so failed
attempt to open //usr/lib/libGL.a failed
attempt to open //usr/aarch64-linux-gnu/lib/libGL.so failed
attempt to open //usr/aarch64-linux-gnu/lib/libGL.a failed
ld: cannot find -lGL
```

And whereis libGL.so gives me:

```
libGL: /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libGL.so /usr/lib/libGL.so
```

What is the problem?

Before that I did:

```
cd /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/
sudo ln -sf tegra/libGL.so libGL.so
```

Comment: You need to include the build command you are running.

Comment: what do you mean? I used cmake .. and then make

Comment: Yes provide your CMakeLists.txt in that case.